# How to extract sections of a string in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like specific separations of values within my column to display the first word and the number along with its **'T'** value. I would like the first **'word' that is separated by '-', and its #T value.** ***With the exception of 'Azure' case***,  ***where the first word is separated by '_'***

It is **tricky because some of the #T values are separated by '-',** while **others are separated by
'_'**
ex.  **-12T**  in one of the values , as well as **_14T** in another value
I would like to maintain the original values in the type column

### Sample Data

```py
data = {'type': ['Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0', 'Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0', 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A', 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E', 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C', 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A', 'Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A', 'Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0', 'Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0', 'AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A', 'AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A'], 'free': [6, 5, 10, 5, 1, 2, 10, 7, 6, 3, 0], 'use': [1, 1, 10, 1, 4, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 20], 'total': [7, 6, 20, 6, 5, 1, 10, 3, 2, 3, 20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


                                      type  free  use  total
0   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0     6    1      7
1   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0     5    1      6
2     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A    10   10     20
3     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E     5    1      6
4     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C     1    4      5
5     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A     2    1      1
6   Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A    10    0     10
7             Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0     7    4      3
8             Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0     6    3      2
9      AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A     3    0      3
10     AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A     0   20     20
```

**Desired:**

```
   Name                                          type                free   use  total
  
   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0        Azure               6       1    7       
   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0        Azure               5       1    6                                       
   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A          Hello   12T         10      10  20
   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E          Hello   12T         5       1    6
   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C          Hello   50T         1       4    5
   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A          Hello   50T         2       1    1
   Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A        Happy   90T         10      0   10
   Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0                  Kind    14T         7      4    3
   Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0                  Kind    14T         6      3    2
   AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A           AY14.5  6.4T        3      0    3
   AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A           AY14.5  6.4T        0      20   20
```

**Doing:**

```
df['type']= df['type'].str.extract(r'(^\w+.\d|^\w+)')+' '+df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)')
```

**This works below**, **however, the 'AZURE' value disappears, and the original value is not maintained**.
I am still researching this, any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: use `df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)').fillna('')` instead of `df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)')`, then  the 'AZURE' value will not disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) and last add [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), also is added `expand=False` to [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for `Series`.

For new column for second position is used [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html).

```
s = (df['type'].str.replace('_','-')
               .str.extract(r'(^\w+.\d|^\w+)', expand=False)
               .str.cat(df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)', expand=False), 
                        sep=' ', 
                        na_rep='')
               .str.strip())
```

Thank you @Trenton McKinney for another solution - splitting values and get first one values of lists:

```
s = (df['type'].str.split('_|-')
               .str[0]
               .str.cat(df['type'].str.extract(r'(\d.\d+T|\d+T)', expand=False), 
                        sep=' ', 
                        na_rep='')
               .str.strip())

df = df.rename(columns={'type': 'Name'})
df.insert(1, 'type', s)
print (df)
                                      Name         type  free  use  total
0   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0        Azure     6    1      7
1   Azure_Standard_E64is_v4_SPECIAL_DB-A.0        Azure     5    1      6
2     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A    Hello 12T    10   10     20
3     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E    Hello 12T     5    1      6
4     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C    Hello 50T     1    4      5
5     Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A    Hello 50T     2    1      1
6   Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A    Happy 90T    10    0     10
7             Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0     Kind 14T     7    4      3
8             Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0     Kind 14T     6    3      2
9      AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A  AY14.5 6.4T     3    0      3
10     AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A  AY14.5 6.4T     0   20     20
```

Comment: Ok thank you- is there a way to maintain the original values in that type column? I will try this

Comment: `df['type'].str.replace('_','-').str.split('-', expand=True)[0]` also works for the first part

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney - thank you, I a bit change it, but your idea is used.

Comment: @Lynn It's to bad you don't need the `'DA'`. I noticed that the group of words you want is always at index 5, if you split the string. So the entire thing could be something like `df['type'].str.split('_|-', expand=True).iloc[:, [0, 5]]`. However, the excellent answer from jezrael gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: thank you for the assistance with this- I am trying this now